# Just need a simple way to request rest data from my server from windows phone

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8, async-await

I spent an hour looking but can't seem to find the answer.. this was easy when I would just reference a service and use callbacks.. but from windows Phone 8 how do I simply read the json from

http://punkoutersoftware.azurewebsites.net/api/Score
(simple test data there)

For starters I would be happy to have the RAW Text.. from there Id like to get it in an object.. or if there is a 'Getting REST data into your windows phone 8 app 101' article somewhere that would help..

I assume I would be using the new async/await somehow as wwell..

My best attempt so far is

```
   private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uriString = "http://punkoutersoftware.azurewebsites.net/api/Score";
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);
        var httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

        httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(OnGettingResponse), httpWebRequest);
    }



    private void OnGettingResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var req = ar.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(ar);
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    }
```

EDIT 1:

Is this all I need?  The responseBodyAsText seems to have no value in it after I run that line?

```
  private async void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        string responseBodyAsText = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://punkoutersoftware.azurewebsites.net/api/Score");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [HttpClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx), it's less clunky and have friendlier syntax.

There's no shortcut for getting data into the phone, minimally, you would have to create a class and deserialize the json string into objects. Several useful tools are available, such as [JSON.net](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) for deserialization and [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for lazy people like u and me to create classes directly from json

i would also reconsider putting the http request in other events, putting it within the loaded event would trigger it every time the user navigates back and forth

Comment: according to this httpWebRequest should be used instead.. Windows phone 8 does not seem to have HttpCLient? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/9b4c1ef2-853c-468a-bca8-97477a02583c/

Comment: you are half correct that wp8 doesn't have HttpClient, but recently, microsoft published a portal HttpClient, take a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: well i can't seem to get the nuget package installed on vs 2012 and .net 4.5. it seems to be working for the other people

Answer (score 1):

There are two libraries that can help you with REST in Windows Phone application: 'Hammock for Windows Phone' and 'RestSharp'. Both are very rich and can simplify deserialization.

Comment: looks like restsharp does not work for windows 8 phone ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852256/does-restsharp-is-not-support-windows-phone-8

Comment: I am successfully using RestSharp on my Windows Phone 8. Also, since RestSharp is not platform dependant, I am actually using it in a shared code that can run on Windows Phone 8, Android and IOS devices.